# AndEngine - Sound set in ParentScene plays in ChildScene too

Tags: android, andengine, scene

I have 3 Scenes.

1. GameModeScene
2. PlayModeScene
3. GameScene

In GameModeScene and PlayModeScene i'm playing sound whenever user touches scene

```
-public class GameModeScene extends Scene implements IOnSceneTouchListener{}
-public class PlayModeScene extends Scene implements IOnSceneTouchListener{}
```

This is how i'm playing sound onSceneTouchEvent

```
public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene,TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {

    if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()){
      // This Method plays sound
       this.animateSparkles(pSceneTouchEvent.getX(),pSceneTouchEvent.getY());
    }
    return false;
}
```

While Changing the scenes i set PlayModeScene as ChildScene to GameModeScene and then GameScene as ChildScene to GameModeScene .

In GameScene i'm not playing sound anywhere still sound is getting played. It's from Previous Scene obviously.
How can i stop that. I don't want that sound in GameScene.

This is what m doing while changing scene from PlayModeScene to GameScene.

```
 mActivity.getEngine().runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable(){
           public void run() {
                 mPlayModeScene.clearTouchAreas();
                 mPlayModeScene.detachChildren();

                 mActivity.getEngine().clearUpdateHandlers();
                 mPlayModeScene.setChildScene(   
                   mActivity.getSceneController().getScene(SceneType.SinglePlayerNewGameScene)
                 );
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting the touchEvent sound in GameModeScene, then this sound might be inherited in both of GameModeScene's children. So if you want the sound to be played in PlayedModeScene pass that scene as the parameter(pScene) in:

public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene,TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {

```
if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()){
  // This Method plays sound
   this.animateSparkles(pSceneTouchEvent.getX(),pSceneTouchEvent.getY());
}
return false;
```

}

(This assumes that you are passing GameModeScene into pScene)